# Select Input device in FFMPEG direct show

Tags: ffmpeg, ffdshow

I want to select my camera for input video through dshow in FFMPEG.
I can do it, But I like to do that by use webcam ID not webcam name...!!!

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video-"A4tech USB Camera" -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.2/live/Camera1
```

In the dshow I should set the name of webcam in the video argument, So I need to set the device number to select webcam.

For example Webcam number 4 instead video="A4tech USB Camera".

Please advise to do that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you have 4 cameras same name?

Comment: as a note, with ffmpeg "now" you can specify device by alternative name, there's also video_device_number parameter for multiple same name devices